# Why are my at jobs running immediately on OS X?

Tags: macos, unix

I want to schedule events for exact times in Mac OS X. It seems like the 'at' command is the simplest way to do this.

I have enabled atrun using the command:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

To test at, I'm using the following one-line BASH script:

```
echo 'foo' >> path/to/log.txt | at now + 2 minutes
```

When I run the script, I get output like:

```
job 17 at Sat May 15 12:57:00 2010
```

where '12:57:00' is indeed 2 minutes in the future. But the echo command executes immediately: the line 'foo' is added to log.txt right away.

How can I make at work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. `at` reads commands from stdin as text, it cannot magically know them from a pipeline.

Your command...

```
echo 'foo' >> path/to/log.txt | at now + 2 minutes
```

...runs *both* `echo` and `at` at the same time, in a pipeline. (Think `cat somefile | grep sometext`) So `at` would receive the word `foo` on its stdin. However, the output of `echo` is redirected to a file, so `at` does not receive anything.

---

The correct command would be:

```
echo "echo 'foo' >> path/to/log.txt" | at now + 2 minutes
```

Comment: You're quite right—thanks for the answer and the clear explanation.