# MacOS 'at' command not working; com.apple.atrun.plist missing?

Tags: macos, unix

I have been having trouble running the 'at' command as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56548065/wanting-to-run-a-script-at-a-certain-time-on-macos-instead-returns-job-4-at-we

I tried running the command in the format given in the answer for this qyestion:
[Why are my at jobs running immediately on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/141535/why-are-my-at-jobs-running-immediately-on-os-x?rq=1)

and it *still* just seems to immediately print

```
job 27 at Wed Jun 12 00:15:00 2019
```

and so I wait for the time given and nothing happens.

---

I've learned that I may need to enable to atrun daemon as in here [Mac OS X: at command not working](https://superuser.com/questions/43678/mac-os-x-at-command-not-working)

However I have been to the directory of /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ and there is no com.apple.atrun.plist file.

I unload and reload the file with

```
sudo launchctl unload -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

and

```
sudo launchctl load -F /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.atrun.plist
```

and still don't see it there. And I still can't seem to execute the 'at' command.

Is there anything I'm missing? I'm running macOS Mojave version 10.14.4.